# Different frequency responses using FFT in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I'm applying different windows to a signal and then get the frequency responses using `fft` function in `MATLAB`. The idea is to isolate the peaks of the signal, removing the noise and reverberation.

Different windows:

[image]

My frequency responses:

[image]

Zoom in the peak:

[image]

I don't understand the reasons why there're differences, especially the peak I get using `Gaussian` (figure 3). I know using the `Gaussian` with small standard deviation I can get rid of the noise, getting a cleaner signal.

Why does this happen? Can you guys give an scientific explanition?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code you used to apply the windows and compute the frequency responses. It's hard to know what we're looking at here. Your Gaussian window is a lot narrower than the other ones, you might be killing a part of the signal that contains that specific frequency.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the code is too long, but basiclly and using the hann, hamming and gausswin functions to do the windowing and the fft to performe the Fourier Transform. 
Maybe I'm really killing that frequency using such standard deviation. I'm not looking for a different solution just an explanation why this is happening. 
Thank you so much for you comment.

Comment: I asked for the code because I think this is a weird effect, opposite of what I would have expected would happen. This is something to try: move your Gaussian window to different places in your signal, see how the frequency content of the signal changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two relevant phenomena here:

1. Windows that are narrower in the time domain have a broader frequency response, and windows that are wider in the time domain have a narrower frequency response.
2. Multiplication of a signal with a window in the time domain is equivalent to convolution in the frequency domain

Your Gaussian window with a small standard deviation is narrower in the time domain than the other windows, so it has a wider frequency response.  Convolution of this wide frequency response with the spectrum of the un-windowed signal smooths out the frequency response of the windowed signal.

Of course this smoothing comes with trade-offs.  As you make your window narrower in the time domain, the spectrum of the windowed signal will become smoother, but the resolution will become increasingly coarse.
.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight! That's a good explanation! Cheers!

Comment: But this doesn't explain the peak... It should have been smoothed out!

Comment: The walls of the peak have been smoothed, but why should the peak necessarily have been eliminated?  The convolution in the frequency domain is of two complex spectra, not the magnitude of the spectra, which is all we see in the plot.  Per your example above, suppose we shifted the Gaussian window significantly to the left or right.  The magnitude of the window spectrum would remain the same, but the output signal would be significantly weaker and different in form because the phase of the window spectrum changed.